# Echo Is Off Error

Tags: file, batch-file, echo

I've been trying to create a program that tell you your IP on any computer.
Yet An Error has  been coming up.

```
@echo off
set t=%CD%\file.txt
ipconfig >>file.txt
find /v "IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . . :" "%t%" >>Other_Details.txt
find /n "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :" "%t%" >>YourIpAddress.txt
(
Set /p 1=
Set /p 2=
Set /p 3=
)<YourIpAddress.txt
echo %3%
pause
```

And then this pops up when I run It:

```
Echo Is Off
```

plz help

Comment: Do you want the LAN IP address or the WAN IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A* way to suppress this message is to use

```
echo(%var%
```

if `var` may not be set.

There is however an error in your code.

`%n` where `n` is `0..9` means "the parameter supplied to the routine in position `n`". Hence were you to run `mybatch one two three` then `%0` would be `mybatch`, `%1` would be `one`, `%2` `two` and `%3` `three`. `%4` to `%9` would be `empty`.

It *is* possible to set an environment variable named `0`..`9`, but retrieving such data is a little more tricky. User-variables should simply not start with a numeric.

Comment: "User-variables should simply not start with a numeric." THIS. +1

Answer (score 1):

`%3%` apparently is empty. If that is the case, then the line `echo %3%` actually translated to just `echo`. Calling `echo` without parameters makes it echo the current echo state. So it's not really an error message.

To fix it, use a dot after echo:

```
echo.%3%
```

That doesn't change the fact though that `%3%` is empty.